# Partial modal view and shrink presenting view iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to present a modal view that doesn't take up the whole screen and also shrinks the view behind it slightly. You can find this on Twitter's iOS app:

[image: twitter account selection modal]

Apple does this on their Mail app too:

[image: apple mail compose modal]

Can this style of modal presentation be found in the SDK? Or do you have to write the code for it on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write that as an `.OverFullScreen` presentation where your view controller has a dark translucent area at the top. But if that's not enough control, then just make a custom presentation where you write your own UIPresentationController - it gets to dictate the size and placement of the presented view controller's view, and it can place the intervening "shadow view" as well.

Comment: I think I'll do the custom UIPresentationController, thanks.